# Hundreds’ place digit of $1993^3 – 913^3 – 1083^3$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

How can I find the hundreds’ place digit of the following number:

> $$1993^3 – 913^3 – 1083^3$$

I have not tried this one since I don't know how to begin.
I can tell the units digit of this but how to approach for hundred's place.
I am looking for approaches on how to proceed with these types of questions.

Comment: You can compute modulo 1000: $-7^3+87^3-83^3 \mod 1000$.  Then take the leading digit.

Comment: These numbers aren't that big, are they? You could compute the exact result in a couple of minutes (it's 5,885,006,373).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They key here is to use [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). What you want to find is the last three digits of $1993^3-913^3-1083^3$, and to do so you can take advantage of the fact that if $x-y$ is a multiple of $1000$ (in which case we say $x\equiv y\mod 1000$), then $x$ and $y$ have the same last three digits. In your case, we have
$$\begin{eqnarray}1993^3-913^3-1083^3&\equiv&(-7)^3-(-87)^3-83^3\mod 1000\\
&\equiv&-7^3+87^3-83^3\mod 1000\\
&\equiv&-343+658503-571787\mod 1000\\
&\equiv&-343+503-787\mod 1000\\
&\equiv&-627\mod 1000\\
&\equiv& 373\mod 1000\end{eqnarray}$$
so the last 3 digits are $373$. This approach works for finding other places (replace $10^3$ with $10^n$) and in other bases as well (replace $10^n$ with $b^n$).

Comment: Thanks so much.Your answer is correct. But i am not able to get this line   "if x−y is a multiple of 1000 (in which case we say x≡ymod1000)"

Comment: @anna Have you seen modular arithmetic before?

Comment: i know mod function. Actually tell me what are x and y?

Comment: @anna I was just making the general statement that for any integers $x$ and $y$, if $x-y$ is a multiple of $1000$ then $x$ and $y$ have the same last three digits.

Comment: OK..alex thank you..got it..:)

Comment: @r.e.s. Oops, that was embarrassing. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

One can do this with *mental arithmetic* if one first employs the binomial theorem, viz.

$\begin{eqnarray} (100 a + 10 b + c)^3\  &\equiv& &\ \ \ c^3& + 30 c (bc &+& 10 (ac +\ b^2))\pmod{1000},\quad \rm therefore \\

1993^3\equiv 993^3\ &\equiv& &\ \ \ 27& +\ 90 (27 &+& 10 (27 + 81)) \\

 913^3\ &\equiv& &\ \ \ 27& +\ 90 (\ 3 &+& 10 (27 +\ 1\ )) \\

 1083^3\equiv 083^3 \ &\equiv& &\ \ \ 27& +\ 90 (24 &+& 10 (\ 0\  + 64)) \\

1993^3-913^3-1083^3\ &\equiv& &-27& +\ 90 (\ 0 &+& 10(81-65))\equiv  -27 - 100\cdot 16 \equiv -627 \equiv 373
\end{eqnarray}$